# How to dump a MediaWiki for offline use?

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to be able to make an offline version of a MediaWiki site on a weekly basis.

The [DumpHTML](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDumpHTML) extension actually does what I want, as it dumps all articles and media files, but I can't see any index of all the articles it have dumped, so I can't navigate in the dump.

Reading about the [XML dump](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aBacking_up_a_wiki) feature MediaWiki have, I wonder if it would be possible to either use a program to view these files or perhaps convert them to html?

Or are there other ways to make an offline version of a MediaWiki site?

Comment: Do you really need an index?  Just start at `Main Page` and follow the links from there.

Comment: Here are [Cam Webb’s instructions](http://camwebb.info/blog/2012-12-20/) for making a static version of a MediaWiki site. Here are [my own](http://reluk.ca/project/votorola/b/wiki-copy/), in case they help anyone. Both give links to the static result ([mine here](http://reluk.ca/project/votorola/b/wiki-copy/wiki-copy.task)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a webcrawler tool which will save the site as HTML files. All the links will be converted, so you can open the main page, say, and then click on links and get to all the site.

There are a number of these tools available. I use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), which is command line based and has thousands of options, so not very friendly. However it is quite powerful.

For example, here is the command line I used to dump my own mediawiki site. I suggest you understand each option though before using it yourself:

```
"c:\program files\wget\wget" -k -p -r -R '*Special*' -R '*Help*' -E http://example.com/wiki
```

Answer (score 13):

You can take the `-pages-articles.xml.bz2` from the [Wikimedia dumps site](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index.html) and process them with [WikiTaxi](http://www.wikitaxi.org/delphi/doku.php/products/wikitaxi/index) (download in upper left corner). Wikitaxi Import tool will create a `.taxi`(around 15Gb for Wikipedia) file out of the `.bz2` file. That file will be used by WikiTaxi program to search through articles. The experience is very similar to the browser experience.

Or you can use [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/index.php/Main_Page), faster to set up because it also provides the already processed dumps (`.zim` files). As the comment specify in order to take other MediaWiki sites for kiwix [`mwoffliner`](https://github.com/openzim/mwoffliner) can be used, it may not work with all since they may have custom differences but it is the only variant I came across.

**Taking Wikimedia stuff with `wget` is not good practice. If too many people would do that it can flood the sites with requests.**

---

<sup>**Later edit for the case you want also the images offline:**</sup>

## [XOWA Project](http://xowa.sourceforge.net/)

If you want a complete mirror of Wikipedia (including images) [full HTML formatting intact that will download in aprox 30 hours](http://xowa.sourceforge.net/), you should use:

English Wikipedia has a lot of data. There are 13.9+ million pages with 20.0+ GB of text, as well as 3.7+ million thumbnails.

[XOWA](http://xowa.sourceforge.net/setup_enwiki.html#cite_note-import_cleanup-1):

> Setting all this up on your computer will not be a quick process...
>   The import itself will require 80GB of disk space and five hours
>   processing time for the text version. If you want images as well, the
>   numbers increase to 100GB of disk space and 30 hours of processing
>   time. However, when you are done, you will have a complete, recent
>   copy of English Wikipedia with images that can fit on a 128GB SD card.

But the offline version is very much like the online version, includes photos etc: 
*(I tested the bellow article completely offline)*
[image]

---

**<sup>Later edit if none of the above apply:</sup>**

If the wiki is not part of Wikimedia or doesn't have a dump there is a project on github that downloads that wiki using its API:

## [WikiTeam - We archive wikis, from Wikipedia to tiniest wikis](https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam)

Comment: In case of dumping a custom mediawiki installation, XOWA is quite capable of doing that (some issues might exist), following article http://xowa.org/home/wiki/App/Wiki_types/Wikia.com is quite useful. Usage of Kiwix with custom wikis is yet to be tested (one need to dump the wiki with https://github.com/kiwix/mwoffliner or some other tool first)